# Getting {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} when making a JSON request to a different url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, jwt

I am attempting to make a `JSON` request to an API located on a different url using `ember-simple-auth` and a custom adapter. When I make the request and check the the console the request returns `Status code: 301 Moved Permanently` and I am returned the error `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

```
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';

const { RSVP: { Promise }, $: { ajax }, run } = Ember;

export default Base.extend({
  restore(data) {

  },

  authenticate(credentials) {

    const { identification, password } = credentials;

const data = JSON.stringify({
  name: identification,
  password: password,
  secret: '012345'
});

const requestOptions = {
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  url: 'https://api.otherwebsite.com/api/auth/login',
  processData: false,
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: data,
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(requestOptions));
console.log(data);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ajax(requestOptions).then((response) => {
    const { jwt } = response;
    run(() => {
      resolve(
        // response
        {token: jwt}
      );
    });
  }, (error) => {
    run(() => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
});
  },

  invalidate(data) {
  }
});
```

When I print the `requestOptions` variable I get `{"async":true,"crossDomain":true,"url":"https://api.otherwebsite.com/api/auth/login","processData":false,"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","data":"{\"name\":\"foo\",\"password\":\"bar\",\"secret\":\"012345\"}"}`

I'm not sure what the issue is, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for an option to follow redirects. .... Or check if your URL is wrong? (Missing https or www)

Comment: @RolandStarke I changed it to https and I am getting status code 200 now, however I am still getting {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custome `authenticator` I used for JWT,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import config from '../config/environment';

const { RSVP: { Promise }, $: { ajax }, run } = Ember;

export default Base.extend({
  tokenEndPoint: `${config.host}/user_token`,

  restore(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  },

  authenticate(creds) {
    const {email, password} = creds;
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      auth: {
        email,
        password
      }
    });

    const requestOptions = {
      url: this.tokenEndPoint,
      type: 'POST',
      data,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ajax(requestOptions).then((response) => {
        const { jwt } = response;
        run(() => {
          resolve({
            token: jwt
          });
        });
      }, (error) => {
        run(() => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    });
  },

  invalidate(data) {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }
```